# PHP, array of objects, how can I use one set of object values as the array keys

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array:9 [▼
  0 => {#279 ▼
    +"id": "103"
    +"name": "In what city did you meet your spouse/partner?"
  }
  1 => {#280 ▼
    +"id": "100"
    +"name": "What is the first name of the person you first kissed?"
  }
  2 => {#281 ▼
    +"id": "102"
    +"name": "What is the name of your favorite childhood friend?"
  }
  3 => {#282 ▶}
  4 => {#283 ▶}
  5 => {#284 ▶}
  6 => {#285 ▶}
  7 => {#286 ▶}
  8 => {#287 ▶}
]
```

This is the dd(). I'm wondering how it might be possible to transform it into a key/value array, using the id as the key and the name as the value. Something like this:

```
array(
  '103' => 'In what city did you meet your spouse/partner?',
  '100' => 'What is the first name of the person you first kissed?'
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of PHP 7, you can use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) on objects, with the third parameter as the column to index by...

```
$questions = array_column($data, "name", "id");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [collections pluck method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck):

```
$collection = collect($array)->pluck("name","id");
```

If you want to get an array back use:

```
$collection->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with:

```
$data = DB::connection()->select($sql);

$questions = [];

foreach ($data as $question) {
    $questions[$question->id] = $question->name;
}
```

Open to any slicker solutions, but this definitely works!